# Is it possible to retain data from subscribe method

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, scope

I am trying to access the data received inside a subscribe method by storing it into a global variable, when i try to console log it, I only see 'undefined'

I tried to write the data on the HTML doc, where I could see the expected output, but accessing the same variable from a different function does not seem to work

I am working on Angular and TS, and here is the code snippet:

```
import ruleChain from './ev-template/rule_chains/main.json';

export class AComponent extends PageComponent {

  apidata: any;

  constructor(protected store: Store<AppState>,
              private ruleChainService: RuleChainService) {
    super(store);
  }
  createRuleChain(): any {
    let requestBody: any = ruleChain.ruleChain;
    this.ruleChainService.saveRuleChain(requestBody).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.apiData = data.id.id;
        console.log(this.apiData); // returns data
      },
      (error) => {
      }

    );
    console.log(this.apiData); // returns undefined
  }
  installEVTemplate() {
    this.evCreateRuleChain();
    console.log(this.apiData); // returns undefined
  }
}
```

where installEVTemplate is being triggered by a button on the HTML document.

I tried pipe, map , Observer and Observable methods, also tried to return the data from within the subscribe method, also a variable and then returning the variable outside the subscribe but within the createRuleChain function, but even that returns undefined

I am new to front-end development.
Any help to resolve this issue is much appreciated!

Comment: Function inside `subscribe` will be executed asynchronously (i.e. excuted later). At the point you say `// returns undefined`, the state `this.apiData = data.id.id` still not executed.

Comment: @N.F. Then how do I confirm that the data is received and proceed later?

Comment: An easy way is to check `this.apiData` is undefined or not.

Comment: A debugging step is to stick a tap(value => console.log(value)) in the pipe

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from an observable, you subscribe.

You get undefined because that code is running outside the subscription (it runs before the api returns data).

You can put your installEVTemplate code inside the subscribe to use the resulting apiData.

Using RxJs you can create cleaner streams to chain the observables if you need data from one api call for another. The alternative not recommended is nested subscribes.

```
import ruleChain from './ev-template/rule_chains/main.json';

export class AComponent extends PageComponent {

  // observable
  apiData$ = this.ruleChainService
    .saveRuleChain(ruleChain.ruleChain)
    .pipe(
      map(data => data.id.id)
    );

  // rest of comp
  someMethod() {
    apiData$.pipe(
      // use apiData in another api call
      switchMap(apiData => this.someService.method(apiData))
    ).subscribe(someData => {
      // 
   })

  }
}
```

Comment: I tried a similar solution earlier and landed with this error: [link](https://imgur.com/a/c3zFnnt)

Comment: Also would like to know the disadvantages/cons of nested subscribes

Comment: Can’t tell from image but tap signature looks off. Importing this from rxjs?

Comment: My bad, the code actually imported them from 'loadash' , it has no error when I imported it from rxjs, Thanks

Comment: I tried using async await on a function which calls another function which has Promise, and contains the subscribe method within, I have used resolve inside the subscribe method and I am able to get the data on the main function, 
Is this method usable? are there any consequences of this implementation?